# elastic search sort with nested filter not working

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, filter, nested

My documents have an array of objects, each object has a value and a confidence.
I want to sort the returned documents based on the objects property, but only the object which had the matching value to the query.

A document has a property 'tags' containing an array like so:

```
[{"type":"imagga","value":"stone","confidence":16},
 {"type":"imagga","value":"surface","confidence":13},
 {"type":"imagga","value":"texture","confidence":25}]
```

I have tried adding a sort to my search like so:

```
$searchParams['sort'] = [
    "tags.confidence" => [
        "order" => "desc",
        "mode" => "min",
        "nested_path" => "tags",
        "nested_filter" => [
            "term" => [
                "tags.value" => "tree"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

This isn't working. My filter query works, and brings back only matching documents, but they aren't ordered as they should be.

I used this as an example, which looks very similar but didn't work: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/nested-sorting.html
and
http://w3facility.org/question/elasticsearch-sort-by-single-nested-document-key-in-array/

I have also tried changing the confidence field to be not_analyzed which makes no difference, and made sure it was a 'long' type.

Background. My documents represent about 10,000 images, each document has tags with a value and confidence level, so a user can search for something and get matching images based on the confidence set on the tag in the document.

UPDATE:
My Mappings:

```
Array(
    [_source] => Array(
        [enabled] => 1
    ) [properties] => Array(
        [fieldName] => Array(
            [type] => geo_point
        ) [tags . value] => Array(
            [type] => string[index] => not_analyzed
        ) [tags . confidence] => Array(
            [type] => long[index] => not_analyzed
        )
    )
)
```

My query:

```
Array(
    [sort] => Array(
        [tags . confidence] => Array(
            [order] => desc[mode] => min[nested_path] => tags[nested_filter] => Array(
                [term] => Array(
                    [tags . value] => tree
                )
            )
        )
    ) [index] => mediadump_index[size] => 100[from] => 0[body] => Array(
        [query] => Array(
            [function_score] => Array(
                [functions] => Array(
                    [0] => Array(
                        [random_score] => stdClassObject()
                    )
                ) [filter] => Array(
                    [bool] => Array(
                        [must] => Array(
                            [0] => Array(
                                [term] => Array(
                                    [tags . value] => tree
                                )
                            )
                        ) [must_not] => Array()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

My results (some tags removed to reduce this sample):

```
Array
(
    [took] => 3
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 5
            [successful] => 5
            [failed] => 0
        )

    [hits] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1682
            [max_score] => 0.9996578
            [hits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => mediadump_index
                            [_type] => file
                            [_id] => 3173
                            [_score] => 0.9996578
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3173
                                    [hash] => fe535555a08aa13dcfa5d80dd451fbf3
                                    [media_type] => image
                                    [file_type] => jpeg
                                    [medium_width] => 450
                                    [medium_height] => 300
                                    [datetime] => 2013-02-21 13:19:55
                                    [longtime] => 1361452795
                                    [pin] => Array
                                        (
                                            [location] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [lat] => 27.809999465942
                                                    [lon] => 33.459999084473
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [latitude] => 27.809999465942
                                    [longitude] => 33.459999084473
                                    [elevation] => 0
                                    [literal_location] => 
                                    [tags] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => exif.cameramake
                                                    [value] => sony
                                                    [confidence] => 50
                                                    [group] => exif
                                                )

                                            [43] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => sunset
                                                    [confidence] => 9
                                                )

                                            [44] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => tourism
                                                    [confidence] => 8
                                                )

                                            [45] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => travel
                                                    [confidence] => 19
                                                )

                                            [46] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => tree
                                                    [confidence] => 10
                                                )

                                            [58] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => places.formattedaddress
                                                    [value] => red sea governorate, egypt
                                                    [confidence] => 65
                                                    [group] => places
                                                )

                                            [59] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => tag
                                                    [value] => *
                                                    [confidence] => 50
                                                )

                                            [60] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => uniquedirectorypath
                                                    [value] => /africa/egypt
                                                    [confidence] => 50
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => mediadump_index
                            [_type] => file
                            [_id] => 2917
                            [_score] => 0.9489555
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2917
                                    [hash] => 60506e48708ab46d0b619bf5328aa648
                                    [media_type] => image
                                    [file_type] => jpeg
                                    [medium_width] => 450
                                    [medium_height] => 300
                                    [datetime] => 2013-07-09 18:14:34
                                    [longtime] => 1373393674
                                    [pin] => Array
                                        (
                                            [location] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [lat] => -7.5199999809265
                                                    [lon] => 36.659999847412
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [latitude] => -7.5199999809265
                                    [longitude] => 36.659999847412
                                    [elevation] => 0
                                    [literal_location] => 
                                    [tags] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => exif.cameramake
                                                    [value] => sony
                                                    [confidence] => 50
                                                    [group] => exif
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => exif.datetime
                                                    [value] => 2013:07:09 18:14:34
                                                    [confidence] => 50
                                                    [group] => exif
                                                )

                                            [37] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => spring
                                                    [confidence] => 11
                                                )

                                            [38] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => stone
                                                    [confidence] => 8
                                                )

                                            [39] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => summer
                                                    [confidence] => 15
                                                )

                                            [40] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => tourism
                                                    [confidence] => 12
                                                )

                                            [41] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => travel
                                                    [confidence] => 15
                                                )

                                            [42] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => tree
                                                    [confidence] => 22
                                                )

                                            [43] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => trees
                                                    [confidence] => 13
                                                )

                                            [44] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => imagga
                                                    [value] => water
                                                    [confidence] => 8
                                                )


                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can you show the whole query that gets sent out, the relevant mapping for the `tags` nested type and eventually the results you get from your query?

Comment: Done. I'm using php client, has the arrays.